# FCM Notification is not received by client app through node.js

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I am working on an application in which I have to send the notification to android devices from node server with the help of fcm-node/firebase-admin.Server is successfully sending the notification but client App is unable to receive it.The code is given below:

```
var FCM = require('fcm-node')

var serverKey = require('./myapplication3-efc5b-firebase-adminsdk-haq21-361858e343.json') //put the generated private key path here    

var fcm = new FCM(serverKey)

var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
    to: 'e4rIFxa5bUo:APA91bH_eDZjZW1Fh5Ib6gI26fbS66bP7qBvRoe740FQNNox8QgUADt_nEF-7Bxze_lB5LuMA9JJcrbaGzd_VLIWaQPUwF4qWrpsixOTZAxK3YZNydLuZLXDw1SpBiYCAkYhajhUGC2l', 
   // collapse_key: 'notification',

    notification: {
        title: 'Title', 
        body: 'Trial' 
    },

    data: {  //you can send only notification or only data(or include both)
        my_key: 'my value',
        my_another_key: 'my another value'
    }
}


fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response)
    }
})
```

[image: Output of node server]

Comment: Can you share the receiver code on Android?

Comment: I changed the onMessageReceived() a bit and its working now. Thank you for your concern @Aditya Ladwa